# How to use Ternary Operator angular.js and html5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

How can I tell to angular to display the html code to display the flag picture only if the variable that contains the name of the flag is not empty. The name of the flag is in column.field of a ng-grid.

The code below doesn't work correctly:

```
var CellTemplate = '<div>{{row.getProperty(col.field)? "<img ng-src=\'images/country/flag_{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}.gif\' />" : ""}}</div>';
```

The result is displaying like that: {{row.getProperty(col.field)? "*flag picture*" : ""}}

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: You are passing the entire operation as a string. You should do it how you would in plain JS

Answer (score 2):

You can't put html within `{{}}` view expressions. Those expressions only support text.

Try using `ng-if`:

```
<div ng-if="row.getProperty(col.field)">
      <img ng-src='images/countryflag_{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}.gif' />
</div>
```